# not able to run rails app locally

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Hello i am fairly new to rails and i have a rails app which use to run normally before, recently when i am trying to to command `rails s` on my machine it throws me `method_missing': undefined method web_console'` error. I am totally lost. here is the log

```
rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.7 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Exiting
/Users/mohammedsayerwala/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:95:in `method_missing': undefined method `web_console' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x007fa04bb518f8> (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  console
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/Documents/Aqua/config/environments/development.rb:24:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/railtie.rb:209:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/railtie.rb:209:in `configure'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/Documents/Aqua/config/environments/development.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:600:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:599:in `each'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:599:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/Documents/Aqua/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/Documents/Aqua/config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/Documents/Aqua/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/Documents/Aqua/config.ru:in `new'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/Documents/Aqua/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/server.rb:319:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/server.rb:219:in `app'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:84:in `app'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/server.rb:354:in `wrapped_app'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:148:in `log_to_stdout'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:102:in `start'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:90:in `block in server'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/Documents/Aqua/bin/rails:9:in `require'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/Documents/Aqua/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
    from /Users/mohammedsayerwala/Documents/Aqua/bin/spring:14:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

I am using rails 5.0.7 version and ruby 2.4.0
i tried doing `spring stop` and even commenting the spring gem inside the gemfile but nothing worked. 
Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: So it worked before? What changed since then?

Comment: i tried deploying it using capistrano but after since i am not even able to run it on development anymore, i had kept a backup before i started messing with capistrano now when i try to run using the backup directory i am still getting the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue, though i was using the new backup directory i had the `rsa` key in `ssh-add` because of capistrano previous deployment try's once i removed that and tried to run it things ran normally